# Why will my code not recognize checkboxes?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all checkboxes in a range based on partial name match and value, but when I go to debug, it sees no checkboxes and skips to the end. I have over 100 checkboxes in the sheet.

```vb
Set breakRange = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 30))
                
For Each checkbox In Worksheets("Data").CheckBoxes
    If Not Intersect(checkbox.TopLeftCell, breakRange) Is Nothing Then
        If checkbox.Name Like ("*" & "lunch" & "*") And checkbox.Value = True Then
            breaks = breaks + 0.5                            
        End If
        
        If checkbox.Name Like ("*" & "break" & "*") And checkbox.Value = True Then
            breaks = breaks + 0.25
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Your checkboxes are probably ActiveX Controls. `Worksheets("Data").CheckBoxes` would only include Form Control checkboxes.

Comment: any idea what code i should use to cycle through the ActiveX controls?

Comment: Thank you very much!